Compacting Notation of Propagation of Uncertainty Formula into Vectors with Covariance?
This question has a nice solution to compacting the propagation of uncertainty formula when all terms are uncorrelated. To re-iterate, they found that the combined uncertainty, which I will denote $U_M(\vec{\mathbf{x}})$ (uncertainty for measurand $M$ with components $x_i$) can be written as the $L_2$ norm
$$
U_M(\vec{\mathbf{x}}) = \sqrt{\sum^N_{i=1}{\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}u(x_i)\right)^2}} = \left\lVert u(\vec{\mathbf{x}}) \nabla M\right\rVert_2
$$
But, when some components of the uncertainty are correlated, you have to factor in the co-variance. So, there is this formula that is the same as the previous one, but with the covariance scaled by the partial derivatives (See Eurachem's 2012 QUAM here, section 8.2.3). $r_{ik}$ is the correlation coefficient between components $x_i$ and $x_k$.
$$
U_M(\vec{\mathbf{x}}) = \sqrt{\sum^N_{i=1}{\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}u(x_i)\right)^2} + \sum^N_{i\neq k}{\frac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial M}{\partial x_k}u(x_i)u(x_k)r_{ik}}}
$$
However, I am having trouble condensing this into a more succinct form, like with the $L_2$ norm representation, which I really like because it has a nice geometric interpretation.
This question also mentions that the first uncertainty formula above is derived from Taylor's Theorem, which I thought was really neat, but couldn't find a way to fit this into that.
